# Use of count(*) function

Tags: mysql

Can someone write the similar query using count(*) query??

Because this query doesn't take null values

```
select count(b.Difficulty_level) 
From cr_answer_table AS b, cr_response_table AS c
where b.Difficulty_level like 'Medium%' AND b.Q_No = c.Q_No And b.Correct_answer = c.Answer_Marked
group by CR_Id
```